# Who are RedBelly parodying in Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

RedBelly remind me so much of another two set of characters with a very similar repertoire, but I can't for the life of me place a name. I assume I'm thinking of some sort of '50s commentators.

I have read the [Borderlands wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/RedBelly), which mentions that RedBelly is a play on Ned Kelly, who lived from 1854-1880, long before radio was even invented. Secondly, Ned Kelly is a single person, who can't be the basis of a parody by two individuals (unless he had disassociative identity disorder).

Attributes of Red:

- Either isn't very bright or doesn't want to fight, seen when he says, "tea?" And Belly has to respond "No, death!".

Attributes of Belly:

- The more rational of the two. Tends to set the tone for both of them.
- The only time he says something like Red is on an ECHO device when he says, "Red and Belly sitting in a tree. K-I-S-S... wait, that's weird."

Comment: "Easy" questions are not off topic, and the fact that an answer can be found with a Google search does not make questions off topic either. I've purged comments arguing about this frivolity.

Answer (score 12):

It is definitely a reference to Ned Kelly, who built a suit of armor that is very similar in appearance to RedBelly's armor.. 
 [image: Ned Kelly]

Ned Kelly

[image: RedBelly]

RedBelly

They also appear to be a reference to [Master Blaster](http://madmax.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Blaster) from [Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Max_Beyond_Thunderdome).  They also were a combination of the tiny smart character teamed up with a large dumb character.

[image]

Comment: +1, great image. However, I'm looking more for where their personalities come from, not just the design.

Comment: Updating my answer....